# Compile error using Azure Storage Client library 3.0 method executequery<T> where T is tableentity

Tags: c#-4.0, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I must be missing something obvious but the following fails with a compile error:

```
internal static IEnumerable<T> GetEntitiesWithCommaSeparatedRowKeys<T>(
string tableName, string partitionKey, 
string commaDelimitedStringOfRowKeys) where T: TableEntity
{
 ....
    TableQuery<T> entitiesQuery = new TableQuery<T>().Where(
                 TableQuery.CombineFilters(
                           TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey",
                           QueryComparisons.Equal, partitionKey),
                           TableOperators.And,
                           AzureHelper.GetFilterConditionForCommaDelimitedStringOfRowKeys(commaDelimitedStringOfRowKeys)
                           ));
    // compile error on this line
    IEnumerable<T> entities = table.ExecuteQuery<T>(entitiesQuery);
 ...
 }
```

The error I get is:

```
'T' must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor 
in order to use it as parameter 'TElement' in the generic type or 
method 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.CloudTable.ExecuteQuery<TElement>
(Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableQuery<TElement>, 
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableRequestOptions, 
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.OperationContext)'
```

TableEntity clearly has a public parameterless constructor and is non-abstract.
The following is the object from metadata info when I hit F12 on TableEntity (just to ensure its resolving the TableEntity type correctly).

```
namespace Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table
{

    public class TableEntity : ITableEntity
    {
        // Summary:
        //     Initializes a new instance of the Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableEntity
        //     class.
        public TableEntity();
        ...
    }
}
```

Any ideas anyone? 
FYI I'm using Azure Client library 3.0.1.0.

UPDATE: Added [linked issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13480039/tablequeryt-from-azure-tablestorage-that-filters-on-partitionkey?rq=1) which solved a similar problem

Answer (score 10):

So turns out that if a method provides a constraint on type, that constraint must be also forwarded by any callers of that type.

I didn't know that.

In this case the definition for Table.ExecuteQuery looks like the following

```
 public IEnumerable<TElement> ExecuteQuery<TElement>(TableQuery<TElement> query,
         TableRequestOptions requestOptions = null,
         OperationContext operationContext = null) 
                where TElement : ITableEntity, new();
```

Therefore adding new() to my constraints for T fixes the issue.

So the final method declaration looks like

```
internal static IEnumerable<T> GetEntitiesWithCommaSeparatedRowKeys<T>(string tableName,
       string partitionKey,
       string commaDelimitedStringOfRowKeys) 
              where T : TableEntity , new() //This is new (pun intended :))
```

Found a related issue in one of the [related links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13480039/tablequeryt-from-azure-tablestorage-that-filters-on-partitionkey?rq=1) that showed up for this question.

I'm guessing the compiler could always look up the type constraints from when I actually make the call, but since TableEntity is public (and not sealed) I guess it could end up being a runtime issue.

Also interesting to note that my method is marked internal which should really enable the compiler to check against callers within the library.

Anyways, learnt something new :).

Comment: Thanks for sharing, yes it works. The new() is there to initialize the paramaterless constructor of the TElement generic which must be  of the type TableEntity. That is why it is needed to have a paramaterless constructor when you define your class that inherits from TableEntity. You saved me some time troubleshooting, thanks.